# calculate determinant calculation in java

Tags: java, matrix

I am calculating the inverse of a matrix using the adjoint method. first i have to calculate the determinant of the matrix. to calculate the determinant I first create an upper triangular matrix and then multiply the diagonals to get the determinant of the matrix. the fomular for calculating the determinant is given below.

```
for(int cr = 1 ;cr < dd.length;cr++)
{ double factor = 0.0;      
  final   double[] firstrow = new double[dd.length] ; /* dd is a matrix*/

  for(int r = 0 ;r < dd.length; r++)  
 { firstrow[r] = dd[cr - 1][r]; }

for( int rowcount = cr + 0 ; rowcount< dd.length ; rowcount++)
{           
  factor = dd[rowcount][cr - 1] / firstrow[cr - 1];

for( int m = cr - 1 ; m < firstrow.length ; m++)
{  
dd[cr - 1][m] = firstrow[m] * factor;               /* multioly row by factor */                                                
dd[rowcount][m] = dd[rowcount][m] - dd[cr - 1][m];  /* our current row minus factored row */
dd[cr - 1][m] = firstrow[m];                        /* restore the original values to row */    
}    }} 

for(int d = 0 ; d < dd.length;d++)
{det *= dd[d][d];}    /* det is the determinant */
```

after getting the lower triangular matrix , the product of the diagonal values becomes the determinant of the matrix. I have tried this method and it works. however when I use it to calculate the determinant of a 13 by 13 matrix with floating point values , I get a not a number value that is NaN as the determinant. 
Can someone please explain to me what is happening. 
I have below example values of the matrix.

```
65.15078176822551
 731.664756199619
 1.5309584518179011E9
 1.7388182254012366E11
 3.3604905770182707E17
 1.77135880331128576E17
```

thank all

Comment: Did you initialize 'det' somewhere?  Also, it isn't clear what you mean by "example values of the matrix".  Example diagonal values?  Example determinants?

Comment: @Joey - you have a good point about `det`,but that won't be the cause of NaNs.  If `det` was not explicitly initialized it would have a value of zero (or he'd see a compilation error).

Comment: @Stephen - you are totally right about how variables are implicitly initialized in Java, but if he did initialize det somewhere and/or used it previously, then NaN could most certainly pop up.  I guess I was just getting at the fact that the question is a bit too incomplete to answer the question.  Still have no idea what that column of numbers is supposed to be.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suspect that the problem is something to do with your use of `factor` to (I'm guessing) reduce the scale of the numbers.  My bet is that `firstrow[cr - 1]` is zero for some index.  The ensuing division by zero will create and INF or a NaN, and that will propagate through the rest of the calculation.

---

Incidentally, this "formula" doesn't look like the standard method for calculating determinants, as explained here:

http://www.math.dartmouth.edu/archive/m8s00/public_html/handouts/matrices3/node7.html

The standard version doesn't involve any division.  Are you sure that your "formula" is correct?

Comment: yes , I used the standard method at first but the system just hangs up and never gives a result. this is a code snippet of the first method I used.                                            if(m.length ==2)
  {return m[0][0] * m[1][1] - m[0][1] * m[1][0];}
  
  for(int k = 0;k < m.length; k++)
  {  double[][] g = subMatrixOfElements(m ,0, k); 
  det += signMatrix(k) * m[0][k] * determinants(g); }
  return det; }                                         
Note : the det variable always reinitialize to 0.0

Comment: 1) My diagnosis still stands.  The problem is most likely caused by a division by zero at the place indicated. 2) The problem in your first attempt is not with standard method itself, but with the way you implemented it.  You should have stuck with the standard method and fixed the bug in your code.

Answer (score 0):

Try this one and you'll get the accurate determinant of a matrix **with any dimension.**

This class uses many different methods to **make the matrix triangular** and then, calculates the determinant of it. It can be used for matrix of high dimension like 500 x 500 or even more. the bright side of the this class is that you can get the **result in BigDecimal** so there is no infinity and **you'll have always the accurate answer**. By the way, using many various methods and avoiding recursion resulted in much faster way with higher performance to the answer. hope it would be helpful.

```
import java.math.BigDecimal;


public class DeterminantCalc {

private double[][] matrix;
private int sign = 1;


DeterminantCalc(double[][] matrix) {
    this.matrix = matrix;
}

public int getSign() {
    return sign;
}

public BigDecimal determinant() {

    BigDecimal deter;
    if (isUpperTriangular() || isLowerTriangular())
        deter = multiplyDiameter().multiply(BigDecimal.valueOf(sign));

    else {
        makeTriangular();
        deter = multiplyDiameter().multiply(BigDecimal.valueOf(sign));

    }
    return deter;
}


/*  receives a matrix and makes it triangular using allowed operations
    on columns and rows
*/
public void makeTriangular() {

    for (int j = 0; j < matrix.length; j++) {
        sortCol(j);
        for (int i = matrix.length - 1; i > j; i--) {
            if (matrix[i][j] == 0)
                continue;

            double x = matrix[i][j];
            double y = matrix[i - 1][j];
            multiplyRow(i, (-y / x));
            addRow(i, i - 1);
            multiplyRow(i, (-x / y));
        }
    }
}


public boolean isUpperTriangular() {

    if (matrix.length < 2)
        return false;

    for (int i = 0; i < matrix.length; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < i; j++) {
            if (matrix[i][j] != 0)
                return false;

        }

    }
    return true;
}


public boolean isLowerTriangular() {

    if (matrix.length < 2)
        return false;

    for (int j = 0; j < matrix.length; j++) {
        for (int i = 0; j > i; i++) {
            if (matrix[i][j] != 0)
                return false;

        }

    }
    return true;
}


public BigDecimal multiplyDiameter() {

    BigDecimal result = BigDecimal.ONE;
    for (int i = 0; i < matrix.length; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < matrix.length; j++) {
            if (i == j)
                result = result.multiply(BigDecimal.valueOf(matrix[i][j]));

        }

    }
    return result;
}


// when matrix[i][j] = 0 it makes it's value non-zero
public void makeNonZero(int rowPos, int colPos) {

    int len = matrix.length;

    outer:
    for (int i = 0; i < len; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < len; j++) {
            if (matrix[i][j] != 0) {
                if (i == rowPos) { // found "!= 0" in it's own row, so cols must be added
                    addCol(colPos, j);
                    break outer;

                }
                if (j == colPos) { // found "!= 0" in it's own col, so rows must be added
                    addRow(rowPos, i);
                    break outer;
                }
            }
        }
    }
}


//add row1 to row2 and store in row1
public void addRow(int row1, int row2) {

    for (int j = 0; j < matrix.length; j++)
        matrix[row1][j] += matrix[row2][j];
}


//add col1 to col2 and store in col1
public void addCol(int col1, int col2) {

    for (int i = 0; i < matrix.length; i++)
        matrix[i][col1] += matrix[i][col2];
}


//multiply the whole row by num
public void multiplyRow(int row, double num) {

    if (num < 0)
        sign *= -1;


    for (int j = 0; j < matrix.length; j++) {
        matrix[row][j] *= num;
    }
}


//multiply the whole column by num
public void multiplyCol(int col, double num) {

    if (num < 0)
        sign *= -1;

    for (int i = 0; i < matrix.length; i++)
        matrix[i][col] *= num;

}


// sort the cols from the biggest to the lowest value
public void sortCol(int col) {

    for (int i = matrix.length - 1; i >= col; i--) {
        for (int k = matrix.length - 1; k >= col; k--) {
            double tmp1 = matrix[i][col];
            double tmp2 = matrix[k][col];

            if (Math.abs(tmp1) < Math.abs(tmp2))
                replaceRow(i, k);
        }
    }
}


//replace row1 with row2
public void replaceRow(int row1, int row2) {

    if (row1 != row2)
        sign *= -1;

    double[] tempRow = new double[matrix.length];

    for (int j = 0; j < matrix.length; j++) {
        tempRow[j] = matrix[row1][j];
        matrix[row1][j] = matrix[row2][j];
        matrix[row2][j] = tempRow[j];
    }
}


//replace col1 with col2
public void replaceCol(int col1, int col2) {

    if (col1 != col2)
        sign *= -1;

    System.out.printf("replace col%d with col%d, sign = %d%n", col1, col2, sign);
    double[][] tempCol = new double[matrix.length][1];

    for (int i = 0; i < matrix.length; i++) {
        tempCol[i][0] = matrix[i][col1];
        matrix[i][col1] = matrix[i][col2];
        matrix[i][col2] = tempCol[i][0];
    }
}
```

}

And then this class receives a matrix of n x n from the user or can generate a random matrix of nxn and then calculates it's determinant. It also shows the solution and the final triangular matrix.

```
import java.math.BigDecimal;
import java.security.SecureRandom;
import java.text.NumberFormat;
import java.util.Scanner;


public class DeterminantTest {

public static void main(String[] args) {

    String determinant;

    //generating random numbers
int len = 500;
SecureRandom random = new SecureRandom();
double[][] matrix = new double[len][len];

for (int i = 0; i < len; i++) {
    for (int j = 0; j < len; j++) {
        matrix[i][j] = random.nextInt(500);
        System.out.printf("%15.2f", matrix[i][j]);
    }
}
System.out.println();

/*double[][] matrix = {
    {1, 5, 2, -2, 3, 2, 5, 1, 0, 5},
    {4, 6, 0, -2, -2, 0, 1, 1, -2, 1},
    {0, 5, 1, 0, 1, -5, -9, 0, 4, 1},
    {2, 3, 5, -1, 2, 2, 0, 4, 5, -1},
    {1, 0, 3, -1, 5, 1, 0, 2, 0, 2},
    {1, 1, 0, -2, 5, 1, 2, 1, 1, 6},
    {1, 0, 1, -1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1},
    {1, 5, 5, 0, 3, 5, 5, 0, 0, 6},
    {1, -5, 2, -2, 3, 2, 5, 1, 1, 5},
    {1, 5, -2, -2, 3, 1, 5, 0, 0, 1}
};

    double[][] matrix = menu();*/

    DeterminantCalc deter = new DeterminantCalc(matrix);

    BigDecimal det = deter.determinant();

    determinant = NumberFormat.getInstance().format(det);

    for (int i = 0; i < matrix.length; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < matrix.length; j++) {
            System.out.printf("%15.2f", matrix[i][j]);
        }
        System.out.println();
    }

    System.out.println();
    System.out.printf("%s%s%n", "Determinant: ", determinant);
    System.out.printf("%s%d", "sign: ", deter.getSign());

}


public static double[][] menu() {

    Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);

    System.out.print("Matrix Dimension: ");
    int dim = scanner.nextInt();

    double[][] inputMatrix = new double[dim][dim];

    System.out.println("Set the Matrix: ");
    for (int i = 0; i < dim; i++) {
        System.out.printf("%5s%d%n", "row", i + 1);
        for (int j = 0; j < dim; j++) {

            System.out.printf("M[%d][%d] = ", i + 1, j + 1);
            inputMatrix[i][j] = scanner.nextDouble();
        }
        System.out.println();
    }
    scanner.close();

    return inputMatrix;
}
```

}